# File upload - Node Js(Express) to React Js. How to get correct image path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I'm working on local system and developing file upload feature in node js. Currently my file structure is like below.

```
Project
..client
.... source code of React App
..Server
....uploads
......avatar
........image.png
....index.js
```

Here server is Node js code and Client is React js code.

So I've developed one API to upload image into 'server/uploads/avatar'. As you can see there is one image named 'avatar.png' is there in 'uploads' folder.

My Question is that what path to show to access that particular image with full domain path? I want this kind of result in API.
Ex.
{ avatar: "http://192.168.1.100:3000/*" }. Consider * as remaining image path. But i'm not able to access image on client side. I don't know if this is the correct way. 
May be i need to set static path for Nodejs in index.js file. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set static folder path in express configurations like below:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

ofcourse you will need to create new folder with this name and then you can put all the assets in that, after that you will be able to access files like below:

```
http://localhost:3000/kitten.jpg
```

Comment: But i also need to set static path for React js 'index.html to run on node server. 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

Comment: you just have to add the path to image in your component relative to public folder, and express will automatically serve the requested file. You don't have to handle this functionality.